# Levi-Civita Connection Example of a calculation

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, connections

Does anyone know of an explicit calculation of a Levi-Civita connection? It is a map from $V\times V \rightarrow V$ where $V$ is the set of all vector fields on a manifold $M$, so there should be an explicit way of writing such a map for a particular LC connection but I can't find any.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "explicit calculation"? The LC connection may be given in terms of the Christoffel symbols, and these in turn may be computed from the coefficients of the metric tensor. To me, this is pretty explicit and concrete.

Comment: Is there a way of giving the connection explicitly without the use of christoffel symbols? I was told by a professor to never use them as they are awkward to work with...

Comment: No, this is the only concrete way that allows you to make explicit computations. Yes, they may be unpleasant to work with, but to "never use them" is scandalous. That professor should be fired!

Comment: Maybe you should check out an undergraduate text which has examples (as opposed to graduate texts which tend not to). You are welcome to download my undergraduate differential geometry text, linked in my profile.